# Adding a delayed class to queue, but want to remove it after further delay

Tags: jquery, queue, delay, addclass, removeclass

I am no Jquery expert, but adopted a template which as it stands works, but trying to modify it so that any added delayed class disappears later with a further delay.

This code correctly applies an 'animated' class with data-indelay ms delay, but want it to remove the 'animated' class with data-outdelay ms later - tried chaining queues together but didn't work - basic code which applies the 'animated' class shown below.

```
    jQuery('.sr-animation').each(function() {
    if (jQuery(window).width() > 700) {
        var visible = jQuery(this).visible(true);
        var indelay = jQuery(this).attr("data-indelay");
        var outdelay = jQuery(this).attr("data-outdelay");
        if (!indelay) { indelay = 0; }
        if (!outdelay){ outdelay = 0; }
        if (jQuery(this).hasClass( "animated" )) {
        } else if (visible) {
            jQuery(this).delay(indelay).queue(function(){jQuery(this).addClass('animated')});
        }
    } else {
        jQuery(this).addClass('animated');
    }
});
```

Any help gratefully received, as I am out of my depth here.

Comment: Found a solution.. not really sure what dequeue() does, but seems to work..

Answer (score 0):

I THINK I have found a solution.. not really sure what dequeue() does, but seems to work - the class subsequently disappears - just I don't think it does it in the 'outdelay' time period ..

```
jQuery('.sr-animation').each(function() {
    if (jQuery(window).width() > 700) {
        var visible = jQuery(this).visible(true);
        var indelay = jQuery(this).attr("data-indelay");
        var outdelay = jQuery(this).attr("data-outdelay");
        if (!indelay) { indelay = 0; }
        if (!outdelay){ outdelay = 0; }
        var duration = outdelay-indelay;
        if (jQuery(this).hasClass( "animated" )) {
        } else if (visible) {

            jQuery(this).delay(indelay).queue(function(){jQuery(this).addClass('animated').dequeue()});
            if(outdelay>0) { jQuery(this).delay(outdelay).queue(function(){jQuery(this).removeClass('animated')}); }
        }
    } else {
        jQuery(this).addClass('animated');
    }
});
```